# SAPUI5: error while loading the view with an extended control

Tags: sapui5

I've been trying to extend a control following this tutorial  [How to extend a standard UI5 control](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/07/19/how-to-extend-a-standard-ui5-control/). When I run the app, the content is not rendered and there are the following errors in console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - ui5loader-dbg.js:1067
>
> Something went wrong during loading the root view with id application-fioriHtmlBuilder-display-component---app - EventProvider sap.m.routing.Target

I've found the description of the same problem: [failed to load resource](https://answers.sap.com/questions/520785/failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-1.html). However, I didn't face the main error from that post:

> Uncaught Error: failed to load 'i2d/pp/mrpcockpit/reuse/library.js' from resources/i2d/pp/mrpcockpit/reuse/library.js: 404 - Not Found at makeNestedError

Nevertheless, I've modified my Component.js file as proposed in the post. Nothing has changed. What can I do to make it work? 
That's how the code looks like.

App.view.xml

```html
<mvc:View controllerName="my.app.controller.App"
 xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
 xmlns:u="sap.ui.unified"
 xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
 xmlns:custom="my.app.controls"
 displayBlock="true"
 busy="{appView>/busy}"
 busyIndicatorDelay="{appView>/delay}"
 xmlns="sap.m">
 <IconTabBar class="sapUiNoContentPadding">
  <items>
   <IconTabFilter text="Tab1">
    <SplitApp id="idAppControl" />
   </IconTabFilter>
   <IconTabFilter text="Tab2">
    <Panel width="100%">
     <headerToolbar>
      <Toolbar height="50px">
       <Title text="Text" level="H2" wrapping="true"/>
      </Toolbar>
     </headerToolbar>
     <content>
       <custom:Switch/>
     </content>
    </Panel>
   </IconTabFilter>
  </items>
 </IconTabBar>
 
</mvc:View>
```

my/app/controls/Switch.js:

```js
sap.ui.define(
    ['sap/m/Switch'],
    function(Switch) {
        return Switch.extend("my.app.controls.Switch",{
            metadata: {
                properties: {
                    editable: {
                        type: "boolean",
                        defaultValue: true
                    }
                }
            },
            renderer: function(oRm,oControl){
                sap.m.SwitchRenderer.render(oRm,oControl); //use supercass renderer routine
            }
        });
    }
);
```

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnqXq.jpg)

Comment: I've created a new project in the SAP Web IDE with the same name and pasted in your code snippets. The Switch control loads just fine on the second tab for me. Does your page load without the custom control?

Comment: Yes, it loads without the custom control.

Comment: Is there any other controller logic we should know about? Have you tried creating an empty project and pasting in your snippets?

Comment: No, I haven't modified anything in the controller file. I've just created an empty project and now the error is "failed to load 'my/app/controls/Switch.js"

Comment: Can you share a screenshot in your post of the working tree (so what folders and files are in the webapp folder)?

Comment: I've just added it at the very end

Comment: The 'controls' folder is in the app folder, not webapp. If you move it down to the webapp folder, it'll work.

Comment: I've tried this variant too, it doesn't work.. By the way, should I type "Switch.extend("my.app.controls.Switch",{..." or "Switch.extend("myapp.controls.Switch",{..."?

Comment: Ok, with "myapp" the newly created project works. But not the initial one :(

Comment: That depends. Look in your view and look at the 'controllerName'. For example, the controller name is 'my.app.controller.App', then your custom control should be 'Switch.extend("my.app.controls.Switch"){' too. The 'my.app' refers to the webapp folder

Comment: After several reloads it finally works. Thank you! The problem was with project structure.

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance. Good luck.